# Interpretation of two indexes Interaction Term

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients

Respected  Fellows.
I will thankful if someone help me to explain my model results.my model is as follows.
Yit=αPFit+βPSit+δ (PF*PS) it+εit
Where Y is GDP per capita 
PF=Political Freedom Index ranges from (0-10)
PS is political stability Index ranges from (0-10)
PF*PS=interaction term 
I=country and t represent time period.
I know how to interpret the results of two continuous variables but I am confused how to interpret the results of two indexes interaction term.(for purpose of easiness i exclude other control variables here)

My estimated model results as follows.
Y=  -0.009+0.009PF+0.015PS-0.001(PF*PS)
Regard

Answer (score 0):

First: If you have multiple time periods it's likely that an OLS regression model is inappropriate; you probably have dependent data and you need to account for that.

Second: Interpretation of interactions has been discussed many times here. You can search the [`interaction` tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction): and see if your question is already answered there.